# How disable event cell in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html-table

I have code like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cel1
        <td>Cel2
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cel3
        <td>Cel4
    <tr>
</table>
```

How can I disable event jQuery? I tried this method:

```
cell.setAttribute("disabled","true")
```

Comment: Disable what event, and why ?

Comment: Where is the event? There's HTML code in your post only. Please post the relevant JS too. Then we can see what events are attached, and you'll explain us, what events you want to "disable".

Comment: I want to disable event jquery

Comment: That's clear already, now please re-read my comment above, then you should know, what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').unbind();
```

Will unbind all events on td elements.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cel1</td>
        <td>Cel2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cel3</td>
        <td>Cel4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to disable a given cell using jQuery, you'll need to do two things.

First, you'll need to select a cell. You can do this without changing the markup by using the `:nth-child()`, for instance - but to make it simple, let's add a class to the cell you want to disable:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="my-cell">Cel1</td>
        <td>Cel2</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cel3</td>
        <td>Cel4</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Now, we can select the cell using jQuery as follows:

```
var cell = $('.my-cell');
```

### To unbind event handlers from the element

From here, if you want to remove all events which are assigned to the element, you can use jQuery's [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) as Sofiene mentioned:

```
cell.unbind();
```

### To hide the cell in the table

If you'd like to remove the cell from the table by setting CSS attributes, this can be done by setting the `style` attribute using jQuery's [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), for instance:

```
cell.attr('style', 'visibility: hidden;');
```

Comment: This will make the table layout messy. It's better to use `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: Ah, that's what I intended to do, but wrote `display: none` impulsively. Thanks